# Azek trim on bay window box

Tags: trim, pvc

I have a bay window with a (I think) classic 3-sided trim bottom.  The trim is rotting and I plan on replacing it down to the studs and back.  So studs, exterior ply, tyvex and flashing, then trim - either poplar or azek pvc.

Here is the first ask - could you take a look at this video?

https://solutions.dunnlumber.com/projects/using-and-installing-azek-trim

Note how he creates the box structure - he has an outer rectangle of trim over  another panel then insets trim to create a nice 3d effect.

My question, and I looked throughout the article, is what is the first layer? From the video I can see he put down his ply and tyvex but for the first panel, is that azek so he is nailing azek to azek?  I wasn't sure you could do that - I thought it was azek to substrate (ply).

I'll try to ascii draw it.

```
------------------------------------
|                                  |
|       -------------------        |
|       |xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |       |
|       |x               x |       |
|       |x               x |       |
|       |xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |       |
|       -------------------        |
|                                  |
------------------------------------
```

In this "drawing" the `x` is the decorative trim, the box it is in is the inset, and the outer.  So the stuff `x` is attached to, probably azek?

Trying to figure this out so that I can make sure I have enough room as my drip edge fro mthe windows above is only so big.

Thanks.

Meta: Also, if someone with 300+ rep could add the tag "azek" I think that would be useful for others.

Answer (score 2):

Just to follow this up - I ended up using 3/8 ply for my backer, then a sheet of azek 3/8, then 1x6 on the left and right vertical, 1x8 o nthe top and bottom which makes a nice box effect.  Then trimmed the inner box with azek scotia.

I'm not accepting this answer, since it is mine.  But everything worked out just fine.

Comment: A) thanks for the follow up. B) I'm surprised nobody chimed in with thoughts even if they didn't have an answer. C) It's perfectly acceptable to accept your own answer.

Comment: Not only is it perfectly acceptable to accept your own answer, it's actually expected, especially since this "solved" your problem. (As an added bonus, it prevents the system from bumping your year-old question to the top of the stack ever couple of months.)